# Define a factory function that accepts a set of operators as inputs

Tags: javascript, function, operators, factory

I have been working on a simple calculator app using client side javascript and have implemented the program logic for the basic mathematical operations `+, -, x, /`. The code is implemented as callback functions so they can be used in event handlers.

```
   add = (a , b) => a + b
   subtract = (a , b) => a - b
   multiply = (a, b) => a * b
   divide = (a, b) => a / b
```

I have read that factory functions are useful in situations such as this where the structure of each function is similar. However I'm not sure how you can create factory functions the set to be mapped are operators. Something like,
`createOperation("add")` would return `(a , b) => a + b`, `createOperation("subtract")` would return `(a, b) => a - b` etc.

My first thought was to convert everything to a string, concatenate them and then return using eval. Something like `eval("(example) => example.output")`. From what I've read in the MDN docs and elsewhere this is highly discouraged.

Is there a way to achieve this without resorting to the `eval` hack?

Answer (score 0):

```
function createOperation(operator, { a, b }) {
  switch (operator) {
    case "add":
      return a + b;
    case "substract":
      return a - b;

    // .... implement for mul and div operator

    default:
      throw new Error("please provide correct operator");
  }
}

const result = createOperation("substract", { a: 3, b: 5 });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I want to return a function not the result of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Using mapping and a factory function can look like this. You can also use an `enum` to hold action names :)

```js
const mapping = {
  mul: (a, b) => a * b,
  add: (a, b) => a + b
};

const factory = (action) => {
  if (mapping.hasOwnProperty(action)) {
    return mapping[action];
  }
  throw new Error("Action does not exist");
};

const add = factory("add");
console.log(add(1, 2));
```

In this example, we have `mapping` variable, which maps action key to the respective function. `factory` function retrieves each action from this `mapping` variable and returns it. No key found - usually should not be allowed, so an `Error` is thrown.

You can use `Map`, instead of an object, especially useful if keys can be other than string type.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I looking for!